How to pass PowerAutomate variable into Power Query?
I'm looking to use a variable established in my PowerAutomate flow as a parameter or filter in my Power Query. I've figured out how to filter my query based on a parameter, but I don't know how to get the flow variable into the parameter.
I want to be able to filter the query (by date for example) by initializing the date variable in the flow and passing it into the query step.

This is for the online version of PowerAutomate, not the desktop version


I've tried initializing the variable in the previous step but I can't get the variable into the query step.

Just 'Edit Query' and access the variable from dynamic content. What's the catch?
